# PHP read sub-directories and loop through files how to?

Tags: php, loops, directory

I need to create a loop through all files in subdirectories. Can you please help me struct my code like this:

```
$main = "MainDirectory";
loop through sub-directories {
    loop through filels in each sub-directory {
        do something with each file
    }
};
```

Comment: what would you like to do with the files after looping through them?

Comment: This will help you, read the user contributed notes
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) in conjunction with RecursiveIteratorIterator.

```
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/directory');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
    echo $filename . ' - ' . $file->getSize() . ' bytes <br/>';
}
```

Comment: In case it's of use to anyone, `$file` in the above is an instance of [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php), with the methods that go along with that (getBasename, getSize, etc) - took me a little while to figure that out.

Comment: @NickF yeah that is good to know! `$file->isDir`, `$file->isDot` are also  very usefull.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to use a recursive function for this, in case your sub directories have sub-sub directories

```
$main = "MainDirectory";

function readDirs($main){
  $dirHandle = opendir($main);
  while($file = readdir($dirHandle)){
    if(is_dir($main . $file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){
       readDirs($file);
    }
    else{
      //do stuff
    }
  } 
}
```

didn't test the code, but this should be close to  what you want.

Comment: It will fall in infinite loop trying to recursively read directory "." (single dot - current directory). You need to modify your if-statement: if (is_dir($file) and $file != '.')

Comment: thanks, I forgot about that, added it to the code. Glad I put that untested disclaimer :)

Comment: missing closing parenthesis `while($file = readdir($dirHandle){`, otherwise works perfect! Thanks.

Comment: This approach makes it hard in cases where you need the file path as well as the filename

Comment: This approach does not work. is_dir($file) does not check if the $file is a directory or not. is_dir takes absolute paths... and $file is only a sub folder...

Comment: Yes I encountered the same problem, the solution is to append $main to the beginning of $file, so is_dir($main . $file)

Comment: I have a few improvement suggestions for your answer. Alas, the edit of the post was rejected, so I just post the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6260147

Answer (score 9):

You need to add the path to your recursive call.

```
function readDirs($path){
  $dirHandle = opendir($path);
  while($item = readdir($dirHandle)) {
    $newPath = $path."/".$item;
    if(is_dir($newPath) && $item != '.' && $item != '..') {
       echo "Found Folder $newPath<br>";
       readDirs($newPath);
    }
    else{
      echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;Found File or .-dir '.$item.'<br>';
    }
  }
}

$path =  "/";
echo "$path<br>";

readDirs($path);
```

Answer (score 5):

I like `glob` with it's wildcards :

```
foreach (glob("*/*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename\n";
}
```

[Details and more complex scenarios.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

But if You have a complex folders structure `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` is definitively the solution.

Comment: short'n'sweet.  recommend replacing "\n" (linefeed when writing to a txt file) with "<br/>" (HTML line break).

Comment: Good idea about the wildcard! Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 4):

Come on, first try it yourself!

What you'll need:

```
scandir()
is_dir()
```

and of course `foreach`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: If you're going to link to the Deutsch version of the docs at least answer the question in Deutsch.

Comment: @erier My bad, fixed the links.

Answer (score 3):

**Another solution** to read with sub-directories and sub-files (set correct foldername):

```
<?php
$path = realpath('samplefolder/yorfolder');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $filename)
{
        echo "$filename <br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Minor modification on what John Marty posted, if we can safely eliminate any items that are named . or ..

```
function readDirs($path){
  $dirHandle = opendir($path);
  while($item = readdir($dirHandle)) {
    $newPath = $path."/".$item;
    if (($item == '.') || ($item == '..')) {
        continue;
    }
    if (is_dir($newPath)) {
        pretty_echo('Found Folder '.$newPath);
        readDirs($newPath);
    } else {
        pretty_echo('Found File: '.$item);
    }
  }
}

function pretty_echo($text = '')
{
    echo $text;
    if (PHP_OS == 'Linux') {
        echo "\r\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "</br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);  // increase the execution time of the file (in     case the number of files or file size is more).
    class renameNewFile {

    static function copyToNewFolder() {  // copies the file from one location to another.
        $main = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\demo';  // Source folder (inside this folder subfolders and inside each subfolder files are present.)
        $main1 = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\demomainfolder'; // Destination Folder
        $dirHandle = opendir($main); // Open the source folder
        while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) { // Read what's there inside the source folder
            if (basename($file) != '.' && basename($file) != '..') {   // Ignore if the folder name is '.' or '..' 
                $folderhandle = opendir($main . '\\' . $file);   // Open the Sub Folders inside the Main Folder
                while ($text = readdir($folderhandle)) {
                    if (basename($text) != '.' && basename($text) != '..') {     //  Ignore if the folder name is '.' or '..'
                        $filepath = $main . '\\' . $file . '\\' . $text;
                        if (!copy($filepath, $main1 . '\\' . $text))           // Copy the files present inside the subfolders to destination folder
                            echo "Copy failed";
                        else {
                            $fh = fopen($main1 . '\\' . 'log.txt', 'a');     // Write a log file to show the details of files copied.
                            $text1 = str_replace(' ', '_', $text);
                            $data = $file . ',' . strtolower($text1) . "\r\n";
                            fwrite($fh, $data);
                            echo $text . " is copied <br>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static function renameNewFileInFolder() {                //Renames the files into desired name
        $main1 = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\demomainfolder';
        $dirHandle = opendir($main1);

        while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
            if (basename($file) != '.' && basename($file) != '..') {
                $filepath = $main1 . '\\' . $file;
                $text1 = strtolower($filepath);
                rename($filepath, $text1);
                $text2 = str_replace(' ', '_', $text1);
                if (rename($filepath, $text2))
                    echo $filepath . " is renamed to " . $text2 . '<br/>';
            }
        }
    }

}
        renameNewFile::copyToNewFolder();
        renameNewFile::renameNewFileInFolder();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$allFiles = [];
public function dirIterator($dirName)
{
    $whatsInsideDir = scandir($dirName);
    foreach ($whatsInsideDir as $fileOrDir) {
        if (is_dir($fileOrDir)) {
            dirIterator($fileOrDir);
        }
        $allFiles.push($fileOrDir);
    }

    return $allFiles;
}
```