# How to display all images of a directory in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, directory-traversal

I want to display all images from a directory dynamically with the help of javascript.
How can I do this?

Comment: only possible if you already **know** the images in the directory.

Comment: As this is also tagged in php I am assuming you are working with it for your application. I am not a php programmer but I would imagine you would have to iterate over the directory with php and pass a collection to your client side using json at which point you could dynamically build image tags. I've done something similar with asp.net but you'll need a php coder to help you with syntax.

Comment: can we get the file names in a directory in javascript?

Comment: sure you don't want to use php for this, seems the best option

Comment: @Vivek: Why is your question tagged with PHP? if you want to loop through files using javascript? I don't think so it is possible using client-side javascript. You definitely need to look into node.js which offers a method http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readdir for the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js

Comment: @verisimilitude my first preference is using javascript only.if its not possible then i will go for php.

Comment: @VivekParikh, basic php example below

Comment: HTML 5 also provides a FILE API (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) to iterate through files.  you may look into this too.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that it is possible, but if you make an AJAX request to an ASP.NET or PHP (or similar) page, they can list the files in the folder and return it for the Javascript to show.

The cross-domain policy obviously applies.

If you are using PHP, you should use recursion on directories to get the full file structure. PHP has a [Scan Directory Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) that you can use.

Basic code example:

```
function listdir($folder) {
    if (!is_dir($folder)) {
        return array(); //empty if not a folder
    }
    $return = scandir($folder);
    $subfolders = array();
    array_shift($return); //first two values are always .. & .
    array_shift($return);
    foreach ($return as $key => $value) {
        if (is_dir($value)) {
            unset($return[$key]);
            $subfolders[$value] = listdir($value); //recursively analyse the subdirectory
        }
    }
    return array_merge(array_values($return), $subfolders);

}
```

Note: This hasn't been tested, please tell me if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Basic PHP example:

```
<?php

foreach(glob("/path/to/images/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,*.jpeg,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE) as $image){
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this using purely javascript is not possible unless the directory has indexes or you know the file names beforehand. Still an alternative using php is as follows:

- Send an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request to a php file with data as directory name
- The PHP file then access the directory contents using `opendir`, `readdir`, `scandir` etc commands. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014474/php-read-sub-directories-and-loop-through-files-how-to) or [this link](http://www.clanthemes.com/tutorials-view-140-display-all-files-in-a-directory.html) for more details on reading a directory by php readdir/scandir commands or [this(by glob)](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-list-all-files-in-a-directory/)
- The PHP file returns the file names (here image names) as a json object.
- On the client side the ajax response comes as the json object.
- Done! You have all the images in that folder.

Comment: It is possible with pure JS if the directory has indexes. You can ajax request the index and parse it with JS.

Comment: ohk, I assumed that it didn't have indexes, anyways edited the answer