# PHP copy a file to multiple child folders with random names

Tags: php

I have an HTML form and one of the inputs creates a folder. The folder name is chosen by the website visitor. Every visitor creates his own folder on my website so they are randomly generated. They are created using PHP Code.

Now I would like to write a PHP code to copy a file to all of the child directories regardless the quantity of directories being generated.

I do not wish to stay writing a PHP line for every directory that is created - i.e. inserting the filename name manually  (e.g. folder01, xyzfolder, folderabc, etc...) but rather automatically.

I Googled but I was unsuccessful. Is this possible? If yes, how can I go about it?

Kindly ignore security, etc... I am testing it internally prior to rolling out on a larger scale.

Thank you

Comment: You mean you need to add a file to all the existing folders?  Assuming all the folders share a common parent path use [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) to iterate (loop) over all the folders and perform the desired operation.  Or do you mean when creating a the new folder you magically want a file added to the newly created folder?

Comment: I'd like the users to create the directory. Then whenever I want to push a new file to their directory. I can run a specific command to copy this new file to their directory regardless of the name and quantity of the folder.

Comment: Yup.  I'd start with looking at SPL's DirectoryIterator.  Here are some examples of code looping over directories: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014474/php-read-sub-directories-and-loop-through-files-how-to

Comment: @ficuscr Thanks for your help. I'll give it a look tomorrow :-)

Comment: `Kindly ignore security, etc... I am testing it internally prior to rolling out on a larger scale.` - famous last words.

Comment: Lol I know. Most of the time when I post the question, I get many comments not to ignore security. I know it provokes laughter but I felt I had to do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is sad I cannot comment so go on...

```
//get the new folder name
$newfolder = $_POST['newfoldername'];
//create it if not exist
if(!is_dir("./$newfolder")) {
  mkdir("./$newfolder", 0777, true);
}


//list all folder
$dirname = './';
$dir = opendir($dirname); 
while($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if(($file != '.' OR $file != '..') AND is_dir($dirname.$file))
    {
        //generate a randomname
        $str = 'yourmotherisveryniceABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
        $randomname = str_shuffle($str);
        $actualdir = $dirname.$file;
            //copy of the file
            copy($uploadedfile['tmp_name'],  $actualdir.$randomname);

    }
}
closedir($dir);
```

I just want to say, you seem to be lazy by looking for what you want to do. because when I read "I would like to write a PHP code to copy" the answer is in your sentence: copy PHP and list of folders regarless how many? Then just simply list it !

Maybe you need to learn how to use google... If you search "*I would like to write a PHP code to copy a file to all of the child directories regardless the quantity of directories being generated*" Sure you will never find.

Comment: Hi, your comment made me laugh. I tried your code and it gave me the following errors in the error long:
`mkdir() [<a href='function.mkdir'>function.mkdir</a>]: File exists in {path} on line 6

copy() [<a href='function.copy'>function.copy</a>]: Filename cannot be empty in {path} on line 20
`

Comment: Hello. It is because if you try to create a folder already exist, it return this warking. I just added a condition to test it. `if(!is_dir())`