# How can I recursively execute sql files in a specific directory structure trough php?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-update

I have an application with this directory tree:

```
3.0    
    3.0.0
         patch1.sql
         patch2.sql
    3.0.1
         ...
    3.0.2
         ...
    3.0.3
         ...
3.1
    3.1.0
    3.1.1
4.0
    4.0.0
    4.0.1
    4.0.2
```

In every directory I have 1 or more file sql file.

How I can execute these sql file trough php? I need to have the response back (in case of errors).

I found this command, but how I can check for errors?

```
mysql -u yourusername -p yourpassword yourdatabase < sql_file
```

Comment: Review the help section for info on the types of questions that are allowed on SO, and how to ask a question. SO is not a code writing service. You need to show that you have done research, and show what you have tried.

Comment: I'm not searching for someone write the code. I'm searching for the best way for do it.

Comment: Then do as I suggested and review the help section.

Comment: Use a function like `shell_exec` to execute a shell command from PHP.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014474/php-read-sub-directories-and-loop-through-files-how-to for how to loop through all the directories to find the `.sql` files.

Comment: But how I check errors with `shell_exec()` ?